# HTML Form Questions / Console Log

Tags: javascript, html, forms

console.log(value); does not log anything but the number on the left is incrimented everyime i click and it indicates that the console.log() call is made, just not showing what I put into it.

Also, a side question is how could I do this if the javascript is in a different file? Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Star Delete</title>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="StarDelete.js"></script>-->
</head>
<body>OKAY DELETE STAR YES ;D!
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="formValueId" name="valueId"/>
            <input type="button" id="theButton"/>
        </form>
    <script type ="text/javascript">
    var button = document.getElementById("theButton"),
    value =  button.form.valueId.value;
    //value = document.getElementById("formValueId").value;
    button.onclick = function() {
            console.log(value);
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That means value is empty I think.

Comment: yeah, that is what I think. I am not sure why though?!?

Comment: I'm not very good with javascript, but I don't think the value inside the function can access the value variable outside the function. You have to pass the value into the function (I think it's called a closure).

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that right now!

AHh like an onclick or something. I think. cool!

Comment: Value was empty, but not due to scoping, see my answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/3wjRJ/1/

```
var button = document.getElementById("theButton"),
value =  button.form.valueId.value;
```

Here you go, the issue was that you were declaring the value variable when the javascript was first loaded, therefore it was always blank.

Comment: Thank you! Very intuitive answer!